# How to exchange parts of a 3D model in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I wanted to know if anyone has idea how to do the following:

we have a 3D model of a character ..

Now I need to make, is that this "character" have interchangeable parts ...

For example, if you want to add a helmet or armor to the model, I guess I should replace the vertex of the torso or head vertex for the armor or helmet vertex.

That's where the problem comes, as I can know where "the part" starts and where finish and start another part? (in blender so I have separate the character in "groups", arm, foot, head, etc..

I think a possible solution:

i had thought to create an object for each "part" and load as separate models (arm on one side, head for the other and so) and handle all parts as "one model".

but I think it is not right...  you can tell me what is the correct way ? tell me your experience in this case (if you know any tutorial on this subject. thanks!)

i Working in C ++ and OpenGL 3+ on Windows
For modeling using Blender.

Comment: They're called attachment points. Google can tell you the rest.

Comment: Thanks! y find this "key word" in google

Answer (score 0):

Ive never done it from scratch in opengl but in unity what you do is, if you want for exemple a sword in your characters hand, you give the sword model the position and rotation of the bone that is in the characters hand, and the object(sword) will movea cordingly to the hand.

You can obviously do the same for armor, hair and all kinds of cosmetics.

If you want to change body parts like an arm or hand the prenciple is the same, you can for exemple use a tranparente texture for the part you want to switch and simple put the new hand as mentioned above.